# Pass array of colors through xml

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a custom view, and want to provide ability to pass array of colors to it through xml.

I can pass it just using string with some separator, like `app:color_list="#505090;#505090;#505090"`, but that won't support references to colors.xml file.

I don't see anything like this in Android SDK, so I'm wondering, is there are better solution than string approach described?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a string array in a values directory.

```
<string-array name="colorList">
        <item>#505090</item>
        <item>#505090</item>
        <item>#505090</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: No option to retrieve get any kind of string array from TypedArray, used when parsing xml attrs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use color selector

**/res/color/color_state.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="@color/red" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:color="@color/white"/>
</selector
```

And pass it to attribute

app:color_list="@color/color_state"

Comment: Well, each color in my case is not associated with any particular state, I would parse and treat them just like array. So this wouldn't be nice solution I think.

Comment: Sure it depends on your case, but it is just a variant

Comment: @NikitaShaposhnik it seems that architecture of your view is a bit complicated, try to rethink a solution you are trying to use or get

Answer (score 0):

Use `array` resource in your `colors.xml` file, then iterate through it in code:

```
<array name="yourColors">
    <item>#505090</item>
    <item>#505091</item>
    <item>#505092</item>
</array>
```

Then you can iterate through you color array:

```
int[] yourColors = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.yourColors);

for (int i = 1; i < nrOfColors; i++) {
    someObject.setColor(yourColors[i]);
}
```

Comment: No option to retrieve get any kind of int array from TypedArray, used when parsing xml attrs.